# Using native compression API and Windows.Storage.Compression

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, compression

I’m trying to use windows compression API in both managed and unmanaged code – 
compress with a c++ service and decompress with c# console app.

1. I tried to use windows compression API written in c++ to compress, and use  [Windows.Storage.Compression library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920921(v=vs.85).aspx) to decode with c#. 
   The decompression failed, because it was not in the format it was expecting.
   I took the compression code from here: [Compression sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Compression-sample-9d57900f).
   Is there a way to make it work?
2. Failing that, I could use the Windows.Storage.Compression library in the C++ service as well. I got it compiling in a C++ console app.
   The thing is, that the c++ code is supposed to be a part of a windows service, 
   And this library is a winRT library. Are there any restrictions regarding using a winRT library in a service?
3. Failing that, I guess I'll need to use the native Windows compression API in both the native C++ service and in the C# app. 
   In C# I'll have to use P/Invoke for it. Is this the only option for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The solution is:

### On c++ side:

Compress with compression API in [**buffer mode**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh968104(v=vs.85).aspx) rather than in block mode

### On c# side:

Decompress with Windows.Storage.Compression library ([sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Compression-sample-9d57900f))